# QT: Unexpected GDB Exit

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qml, gdb

I am trying to debug by QT and QML application.
When i run debugging and set a break points.
GDB pops with Unexpected GDB exit.

When looking into logs
I found below error
status 1, exit code -1073741819 (0x-3ffffffb)

Can anyone let me know why is this happning ?

Comment: -1073741819 is 0xC0000005 (Access Violation), so it crashed. If it's an older gdb, maybe try to update.